# Fit gaussians (or other distributions) on my data using python

Tags: python, database, gaussian

I have a database of features, a 2D np.array (2000 samples and each sample contains 100 features, 2000 X 100). I want to fit gaussian distributions to my database using python. My code is the following:

```
data = load_my_data() # loads a np.array with size 2000x200
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components= 50, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(data)
```

I am not sure about the parameters for example the covariance_type and how can I investigate whether the fit was occured succesfully or not.

**EDIT:** I debug the code to investigate what is happening with the clf.means_ and appartently it produced a matrix n_components X size_of_features 50 X 20). Is there a way that i can check that the fitting was successful, or to plot data? What are the alternatives to Gaussian mixtures (mixtures of exponential for example, I cannot find any available implementation)?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using sklearn package.

Once you have fit, then type

```
print clf.means_
```

If it has output, then the data is fitted, if it raise errors, not fitted.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is not an answer, since what I want to find out is whether this fit is ok ro not.

Comment: You mean you want to judge the performance of the fitting, I missed understand your question. Then maybe try `clf.aic(data)` and `clf.bic(data)`.

Comment: What are acceptable values for aic and bic in the end?

Comment: I got several values for differenct number of components and the result of aic and bic is for sure more than 100.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, I only know the smaller the better.

Comment: Is there any alternative to gaussian mixture models?

Comment: So then what are you going to do with your data? classification? prediction? cluster? Or others?

Comment: I have two different distributions and I want to check the distribution similarities. Before the fitting of the data, I am performing pca. I have notived that if the reduction of the dimensions is not huge (less than 10 dimensions) form the PCA then the fitting performance is above 1000 (aic and bic).

Answer (score 1):

You can do dimensionality reduction using PCA to 3D space (let's say) and then plot means and data.

Answer (score 1):

Is is always preferred to choose a reduced set of candidate before trying to identify the distribution (in other words, use Cullen & Frey to reject the unlikely candidates) and then go for goodness of fit a select the best result,

You can just create a list of all available distributions in scipy. An example with two distributions and random data:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

data = np.random.random(10000)
#Specify all distributions here
distributions = [st.laplace, st.norm]
mles = []

for distribution in distributions:
    pars = distribution.fit(data)
    mle = distribution.nnlf(pars, data)
    mles.append(mle)

results = [(distribution.name, mle) for distribution, mle in 
zip(distributions, mles)]
best_fit = sorted(zip(distributions, mles), key=lambda d: d[1])[0]
print 'Best fit reached using {}, MLE value: {}'.format(best_fit[0].name, best_fit[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, you may like to do regression of two different distributions, more than fitting them to an arithmetic curve. If this is the case, you may be interested in plotting one against the other one, and make a linear (or polynomial) regression, checking the coefficients
If this is the case, linear regression of two distributions, may tell you if there linear dependent or not.
[Linear Regression using Scipy documentation](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/LinearRegression.html)